# Monero-Core build instructions?

Tags: development, monero-wallet-gui, compile, build

It seems some work is being made on monero-core and I wanted to check out the most recent builds. However the repository (https://github.com/mbg033/monero-core) lists build instructions as TODO. Is there a makefile someone could point me to? Running 64bit Linux.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, written instructions for installing Monero on your system can be found [here](https://github.com/moneroexamples/compile-monero-09-on-ubuntu-16-04) with a video tutorial including GUI setup and testing [here](http://sendvid.com/nyyb48w9)

Dependencies:

```
# update Ubuntu's repository
sudo apt update

#install git to download latest Monero source code from github
sudo apt install git

# install dependencies to be able to compile Monero
sudo apt install build-essential cmake libboost-all-dev miniupnpc libunbound-dev graphviz doxygen libunwind8-dev

# or git and all dependencies in one command
# sudo apt install git build-essential cmake libboost-all-dev miniupnpc libunbound-dev graphviz doxygen libunwind8-dev
```

Compilation:

```
# download the latest bitmonero source code from github
git clone https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero.git

# go into bitmonero folder
cd bitmonero/

# apply patch for using Onion Blockchain Explorer (optional)
# https://github.com/moneroexamples/onion-monero-blockchain-explorer
# curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moneroexamples/compile-monero-09-on-ubuntu-16-04/master/res/tx_blob_to_tx_info.patch | git apply -v -
#

# compile the release version.
make # or make -j number_of_threads, e.g., make -j 2

# alternatively `make release` can be used instead of `make`. This compiles
# the source code without compiling unique tests which is faster, and can
# avid problems if there are compilation errors with compiling the tests
```

Installation:

The Monero binaries should now be located in `./build/release/bin`

```
# launch the Monero daemon and let it synchronize with the Monero network
/opt/bitmonero/bitmonerod

# launch the Monero wallet
/opt/bitmonero/simplewallet
```

[image]

Once the above is complete, prepare the source code:

```
git clone https://github.com/mbg033/monero-core.git
cd monero-core
./get_libwallet_api.sh
```

Compile QT:

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev qt5-default qtdeclarative5-dev qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel
qmake
make
```

Launch:

```
 release/monero-core
```